# How can I receive foreign funds in my account in an Indian bank which lacks a SWIFT code?

Tags: india, banking, money-transfer, international-transfer, usd-us-dollar

I'm to receive some money in USD from a company directly to my account.
I'm a resident of India and the branch where I have my account doesn't have a SWIFT code. The company will not give the money by cash/cheque.
Is there any way I can receive such international transfers in my account if the bank branch itself is not SWIFT enabled?
My account is with Indian Bank, if that's relevant. And it's a savings account.

Comment: Open an account at a bank which offers this service?

Comment: Go and talk to the bank on how to do it. They will tell you the options you can use.

Comment: Note that in many countries, you cannot transfer directly to/from a savings account from/to external sources (only from/to your other accounts), so you may need to have a regular "checking" or "current" account to be able to receive the funds. Check with your bank for details. Also note that in some instances, there may be large fees for receiving foreign payments, receiving payments in foreign currencies, and currency exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My account is with Indian Bank, if that's relevant.

Indian Bank already has SWIFT BIC.

> Is there any way I can receive such international transfers in my account if the bank branch itself is not SWIFT enabled?

The Branch need not be SWIFT enabled. However the Bank needs to be SWIFT enabled. Indian Bank is SWIFT enabled and has several Correspondent Banks in US. See this link on [Indian Bank Website](http://www.indianbank.in/remitindia.php#remit)
Select USD as filter in bottom page. It will list quite a few Banks that are correspondent to the Indian Bank. Click on the Link and it will give you more details. For example with [Citi Bank](http://www.indianbank.in/remitindia_form.php?cur=usd&bnk=cita) as Correspondent. In the Beneficiary account details fill in your account details etc and send this to the company and they should be able to send you a payment based on this.